# Apache Airflow: Delay a task for some period of time

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to execute a task after 5 minutes from the parent task inside a DAG.

DAG : Task 1 ----> Wait for 5 minutes ----> Task 2

How can I achieve this in Apache Airflow? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30):

The said behaviour can be achieved by introducing a task that forces a delay of specified duration between your `Task 1` and `Task 2`

---

This can be achieved using [`PythonOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/operators/python_operator.py)

```
import time
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

delay_python_task: PythonOperator = PythonOperator(task_id="delay_python_task",
                                                   dag=my_dag,
                                                   python_callable=lambda: time.sleep(300))

task_1 >> delay_python_task >> task_2
```

---

Or using [`BashOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/tests/operators/bash_operator.py) as well

```
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
delay_bash_task: BashOperator = BashOperator(task_id="delay_bash_task",
                                             dag=my_dag,
                                             bash_command="sleep 5m")
task_1 >> delay_bash_task >> task_2
```

*Note: The given code-snippets are NOT tested*

---

References

- [`example_python_operator.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/example_dags/example_python_operator.py#L59)
- [`example_bash_operator.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/example_dags/example_bash_operator.py#L58)

---

**UPDATE-1**

Here are some other ways of introducing delay

- *UPDATE*: **do NOT use** this as [pointed out by **@Vit.ai**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65095947/3679900). *Original point*: [`on_success_callback`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2430) / [`on_failure_callback`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2421): Depending of whether `Task 2` is supposed to run upon success or failure of `Task 1`, you can pass `lambda: time.sleep(300)` in either of these params of `Task 1`.
- `pre_execute()` / `post_execute()`: Invoking `time.sleep(300)` in `Task 1`'s [`post_execute()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2820) or `Task 2`'s [`pre_execute()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2804) would also have the same effect. Of course this would involve modifying code for your `tasks` (1 or 2) so better avoid it

Personally I would prefer the *extra `task` approach* because it makes things more explicit and doesn't falsely exaggerate the runtime of your `Task 1` or `Task 2`

Comment: I tried this, but it keeps the DAG in the running state, So if my wait time is 2 days, there will be a lot of concurrent DAGs that keeps on running, causing the new DAGS to be in the queued state for 2 days. Is there any workaround such that the DAG while sleeping leave the thread.

Comment: **@Spandan Singh** i can think of 2 possible workarounds **[1]** have a *continuously running DAG* that triggers other dags at right time using `TriggerDagRunOperator` **[2]** keep triggering your dag frequently and if right time hasn't come yet, then skip execution using either `AirflowSkipException` or `ShortCircuitOperator`

Comment: The links are outdated now, one of the corresponding links is - https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2c99ec624bd66e9fa38e9f0087d46ef4d7f05aec/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L594

Comment: @y2k-shubham But when we do time.sleep it halts the current celery worker from picking other task, this way if we have 4 celery worker and 4 task with sleep function and 1 task without sleep, then the task without sleep has no worker left to execute. Correct me if its wrong ? In my opinion better way to wait will be in your current python task, you can check the retry count and if  its zero then raise AirflowFailed exception and apply retry delay of 5 minutes, this way the task will be in sleep mode for 5 minutes without halting the current worker.

Comment: **@Deepak Tripathi** I acknowledge this is a gaping hole in the proposed solution. I haven't been using Airflow for a while now, but do checkout [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59757151/3679900) too

Comment: it did't work with lambda

Answer (score 5):

It's 2023 now, although it's linked in one of the comments, the way to implement this is with `TimeDeltaSensor()` or `TimeDeltaSensorAsync()`

```py
import pendulum
from airflow.sensors.time_delta import TimeDeltaSensor, TimeDeltaSensorAsync

@dag(
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 9, 1),
    schedule=None,
    catchup=False,
    tags=["example"],
)
def example_wait():
    t10 = TimeDeltaSensor(task_id="wait_some_seconds", delta=pendulum.duration(seconds=10))
    t10
```

See [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/time.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work with @once or None scheduled DAGs. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/9046

Comment: In the case of manual runs, use `DateTimeSensorAsync(task_id='wait_some_seconds", target_time="""{{ dag_run.logical_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=10) }}""")`

Comment: Thanks, Also the TImeSensor task worked just fine.

Comment: There seems to be an error in the documentation. `TimeDeltaSensor` waits specified delta after `data_interval_end`

https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/35184

Comment: keep in mind that in airflow, jobs run at the [end of the interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/scheduler.html)

Answer (score 3):

@y2k-shubham gave the best answer to date, however, I want to warn not to use the callback solution. as it first marks the task as success and then executes the callback. which means task2 will not see any delay. if you don't want to use a separate task, you can use something like this:

```py
< ... >
task1 = DummyOperator(task_id='task1', dag=dag)
task1.post_execute = lambda **x: time.sleep(300)
task2 = DummyOperator(task_id'task2', dag=dag)

task1 >> task2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return `pendulum.now()` from first task to init `TimeSensor`:

```py
@task 
def task_1():
  return pendulum.now()

def task_2():
  ...


first_task_finished_at = task_1()
TimeSensor(target_time=first_task_finished_at.add(minutes=5)) >> task_2()
```

[`TimeDeltaSensor`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/time.html#timesensor) is not suitable, because [it waits specified `delta` after `context["data_interval_end"]`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/0bb56315e664875cd764486bb2090e0a2ef747d8/airflow/sensors/time_delta.py#L48):

```
def poke(self, context: Context):
  target_dttm = context["data_interval_end"]
  target_dttm += self.delta
  self.log.info("Checking if the time (%s) has come", target_dttm)
  return timezone.utcnow() > target_dttm
```