# Access python global variable inside airflow task group

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I have set the variable `cluster_key` in a python function which is called via a python operator.

```
cluster_key = ""
new_key =""

def dynamic_list(e_run_id):
    global cluster_key
    cluster_key = 'key_cluster_'+e_run_id+''
    global new_key
    new_key = 'new_key_'+e_run_id+''
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    Variable.set(cluster_key, keys)
    Variable.set(new_key, new_values)
```

When I try to access it inside a task group, it is not able to fetch the variable:

```
with DAG(
        dag_id=JOB_NAME,
        default_args=default_args,
        start_date=yesterday,
)as main_dag:   
    
    
    groups = []
    with TaskGroup(group_id='Dynamic_dataproc_Processing') as dataprocs_jobs:
        start = BashOperator(task_id="start", bash_command="sleep 1m")

        sub_groups = []
        with TaskGroup('dataproc_create_cluster', prefix_group_id=False) as dataproc_create_clusters:
           for i in list(Variable.get(cluster_key)):
               dynmaic_create_cluster = DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
                    task_id="create_cluster_{0}".format(str(i)),
                    project_id='{0}'.format(project_id1),
                    cluster_config=CLUSTER_GENERATOR_CONFIG,
                    region='{0}'.format(REGION),
                    cluster_name="dataproc-clustersrc-{0}-src-{1}".format(SRC_GROUP, (i)),
                    sla=timedelta(minutes=5)
                )
```

Error:
`KeyError: 'Variable  does not exist'`

If I mention `global cluster_key` in the scope of TaskGroup, then it gives the below error:

`SyntaxError: name 'cluster_key' is assigned to before global declaration`

Answer (score 0):

This will not work unless `cluster_key` is set to a default value before the DAG runs.

I suggest creating an airflow variable `cluster_key` set to the value `[]`.
Then running `dynamic_list` in a `PythonOperator` on the first task of the job.

And keeping a longer task `"start"` longer than 1 minute between that and the `dataproc_create_cluster` taskgroup.

Also if you'd like to implement the **sleep* task more efficiently [there is a previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59757151/airflow-implementing-wait-sleep-task-efficiently) you can use.

Good luck!

Comment: I did the same thing. But still getting the error:     for i in list(eval(Variable.get(cluster_key))):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/variable.py", line 138, in get
    raise KeyError(f'Variable {key} does not exist')
KeyError: 'Variable  does not exist'