# Delay between tasks in Airflow or any other option?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

We are using airflow 2.00. I am trying to implement a DAG that does two things:

1. Trigger Reports via API
2. Download reports from source to destination.

There needs to at least 2-3 hours gap between tasks 1 and 2. From my research I two options

1. Two DAGs for two tasks. Schedule the 2nd DAG two hour apart from 1st DAG
2. Delay between two tasks as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002234/apache-airflow-delay-a-task-for-some-period-of-time)

Is there a preference between the two options. Is there a 3rd option with Airflow 2.0? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The other option would be to have a sensor waiting for the report to be present. You can utilise reschedule mode of sensors to free up workers slots.

```py
generate_report = GenerateOperator(...)
wait_for_report = WaitForReportSensor(mode='reschedule', poke_interval=5 * 60, ...)
donwload_report = DonwloadReportOperator(...)

generate_report >> wait_for_report >> donwload_report
```

Answer (score 1):

A third option would be to use a [sensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/sensors.html#sensors) between two tasks that waits for a report to become ready. An [off-the-shelf one](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/index.html) if there is one for your source, or a custom one that subclasses the [base sensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/base/index.html).

The first two options are different implementations of a fixed waiting time. Two problems with it: 1. What if the report is still not ready after the predefined time? 2. Unnecessary waiting if the report is ready earlier.

Comment: The sensor option is the way to go